# probability that k not necessarily distinct numbers are in ascending order

Tags: combinatorics

I know that the probability that k distinct number catch from a set of n number are catching in ascending order is
$\frac{1}{k!}$.
But i don't know what is the probability if the number can are no distinct. I don't know that there is a formula for this.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am sorry if the question is write very well, but my english isn't very good.

Comment: If  you have 3, 7, 7, 10 , do you consider it is ascending order ( equals is considered as succes) or not ?

Comment: It depends on the numbers.  You should be able to do this if you specify how often each number occurs.

Comment: And I think that this question has no answer. You select k numbers. Example k=10.  If you select k numbers (integers) uniformly in range (1,20), the probability to have twice same number is not nul, and the general formula $\frac{1}{k!}$ cannot be used. But if you select 10 numbers uniformly in range (1,100000000), you can use the general formula $\frac{1}{k!}$

Comment: To make a well posed problem out of this:  Say we are choosing $k$ numbers uniformly and independently from $\{1, \cdots, n\}$.  What is the probability that you choose them in increasing order?

Comment: That one I would do recursively, conditioned on the first choice.

Comment: The version posed by lulu can also be approached with stars-and-bars.

Comment: @Lourran, Yes I consider 3, 7, 7, 10 in ascending order

Comment: Thanks, now I will serch something  about stars-and-bars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are allowing repeats by specifying that (some/all) numbers are not distinct, obviously they can only be in weakly ascending order. Also note that each selection you thus make can be arranged in weakly ascending order in just one way.

Then suppose we choose a total of $k$ numbers from $n$ distinct  numbers available in abundance, then by [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)),(note that here $k$ are the balls to be put in $n$ bins, (=$k$ stars, $n-1$ bars)

$\dbinom{k+n-1}{k}$ selections  in weakly ascending order against $n^k$ total possible selections,

thus $Pr = \dfrac{\dbinom{k+n-1}{k}}{n^k}$

Comment: Thanks for your explanation which I found very clear :)

Comment: Glad to have been of help ! Cheers ! $\;\; $:)

Comment: Btw, you could also have used *combinations with repetitions* instead of stars and bars, as explained in this link, but stars and bars is more popular. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4243328/how-do-i-make-sense-of-combinations-with-repetition/4243537#4243537